# EXTJS - What does really happen when I disable a componenet in EXTJS?

Tags: google-chrome, extjs, browser

I was wondering if I change a components (ie. a combobox) status in an EXTJS app from enabled to disabled using .setDisabled(true).

What is it that really happens behind the scenes?
Is it only the CSS that is changed for this component or is it really the component's behavior that is changed?

I'm asking this because I'm concerned about security, whether a user could simply view the source code in the browser and change the attributes of the component back to enabled? Could this be the case?

How can I avoid changes to the components by users?

Comment: You probably shouldn't rely on security implemented on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setDisabled(true)` will add the disabled attribute to the HTML element.

This will mean that if/when the form is POSTed back to the server, the value of that control won't be included. It'll also change the behavior of the control, it'll become unusable and unclickable and by default, disabled controls are rendered in gray by the web browser.

ExtJS I believe will also by default, add a `x-disabled` css class to the component that you can then use for styling purposes.

As stated though, any security implemented on the client side should also be checked server side. Anyone can use IE Developer Tools, FireBug, etc to change values of HTML elements which will circumvent any security rules you put in place on the client.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So assuming there is not a solid server-side check points, if the user on the client side debugs the code and modifies the code, ie. myCombo.enable() then they can see the values/records which were loaded in the combo's store before it was disabled. Is this correct? any explanation would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Correct. The fact that the box is disabled has absolutely no impact on what data is or isn't available in the store of the box. A clued-up user can gain access to it regardless of the disabled attribute.

Comment: What are the best practices in cases like this, I'm guessing to removeAll from the store before disabling... any other good practices generally?

Comment: I'm guessing your scenario is such that you don't want the user to be able to set the combobox to a value not in the store after a period of time and it's not possible. A knowledgeable user who is intent on causing problems could set the value of the box to whatever they want. The value doesn't need to be in the store at all which is why validation must always occur on the server.
If you just don't want the user to have access to items within the store at all (not sure why this would be the case) then again, it's not possible. Everything the browser receives a user can see if they know how.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling any extjs component on the client side you simply change presentation and behavior of your UI. You should ALWAYS make all your security checks on the server-side.

Comment: I will also do a security check on the server side as well, however, just to understand the extjs ui better, I was wondering if someone could explain what really ahppens when I do this: myComponenet.disable(); the css and the js both.